# selenium-python bindings code convert to protactor code

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to protactor. I installed it today.
I was using selenium-python bindings earlier now using protactor. can you help me to convert the following seleniuum-python bindings code to protactor

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Any name").click()

Comment: This two lines as well:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(xpath").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("any_id").click()

Comment: var li = browser.findElement(by.xpath('xpath'));
expect(li.getText()).toBe('Name');
this command is not stimulating any click only throwing error